# How update I18n-js translations.js without reserver restart in development?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I use rails `gem i18n-js`

I work in development mode and I see in every page link to translations:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/i18n/translations.js?body=1"></script>
```

But when I add some keys to my `\config\locales\en.yml`, and reload page, I can't find new keys.

I should restart server and delete tmp directory - that helps

File `\public\javascripts\translations.js` successfully updated after page load, but doesn't go in `/assets/i18n/translations.js?body=1` path